# need help in optimizing query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Actually I am using below query to fetch the result but I feel it is little lengthy query,Can I get help in optimizing below query?

```
SELECT
    o.orderid AS id,
    sd.datestart AS startdate,
    sd.dateend AS enddate,
    o.comment AS comment,
    o.productname AS name,
    o.suspended AS sus,
    o.voided AS void,
    o.invoice_number AS inumber,
    GROUP_CONCAT(js.title) AS sections,
    GROUP_CONCAT(js.sectionid) AS sectionid,
    js.is_science_education AS isse,
    o.amount AS amount,
    js.isbundle,
    o.addedbyuserid,
    (SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            institutiontoorder AS ito2
        WHERE
            orderid = ito.orderid) AS multiple
FROM
    institutiontoorder AS ito
        LEFT JOIN
    subscribedates AS sd ON ito.orderid = sd.orderid
        LEFT JOIN
    ordertosection AS ots ON ots.orderid = ito.orderid
        LEFT JOIN
    orders AS o ON o.orderid = ito.orderid
        LEFT JOIN
    institutions AS i ON i.institutionid = ito.institutionid
        JOIN
    journalsections AS js ON js.sectionid = ots.sectionid
WHERE
    ito.institutionid = '1419'
        AND o.voided != 1
        AND o.suspended != 1
        AND (dateend >= NOW())
GROUP BY o.orderid
ORDER BY o.orderid DESC;
```

I am using multiple joins ,Is it possible to optimize dependent subquery?

Comment: *Is it possible to optimize dependent subquery?* If `orderid` is indexed then nothing to optimize. You may try to move it from output list (SELECT) to rowsourse (FROM), but I doubt that this will improve.

Comment: @Akina Can the query be achieved without the subquery?

Comment: No. You need to count the amount of non-filtered rows. AS I see from your query.

Comment: With respect, it's *really* hard to help you definitively unless you give us enough information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question to give the information needed to troubleshoot slow queries.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite `o.voided != 1  AND o.suspended != 1` as `o.voided = 0  AND o.suspended = 0`? Equalities can exploit indexes more efficiently than inequalities.

Comment: Do you really need `LEFT`?  That is, are you expecting some rows to show `NULLs`?

Answer (score 0):

Minor adjustments to the query such as the select count() to its own pre-query/aggregate, but only for the one institution in question.  Some of your LEFT JOINs actually become INNER JOINS when you added them to the WHERE clause.

I actually moved the AND portions to the respective JOIN locations of said tables joined to.

I would ensure the following indexes on

```
table               index
InstitutionToOrder  (institutionid, orderid)
orders              (orderid, voided, suspended)
subscribeDates      (orderid, dateEnd )
OrderToSection      (orderid, sectionid )
```

Also, you dont need "AS" all over the place such as column AS resultColumn or table AS alias.  It is implied "AS" with just a space after the item respectively.

```
SELECT
        o.orderid id,
        sd.datestart startdate,
        sd.dateend enddate,
        o.comment,
        o.productname name,
        o.suspended sus,
        o.voided void,
        o.invoice_number inumber,
        GROUP_CONCAT(js.title) sections,
        GROUP_CONCAT(js.sectionid) sectionid,
        js.is_science_education isse,
        o.amount,
        js.isbundle,
        o.addedbyuserid,
        preCount.multiple
    FROM
        institutiontoorder ito
            JOIN orders o 
                ON ito.orderid = o.orderid
                AND o.voided = 0
                AND o.suspended = 0
            JOIN subscribedates sd 
                ON ito.orderid = sd.orderid
                AND sd.dateend >= NOW()
            JOIN
                -- pre-aggregate counts once for just the 
                -- institution in question and join to it
                ( SELECT
                        ito2.orderid,
                        COUNT(*) muliple
                    FROM
                        institutiontoorder ito2
                    WHERE
                        ito2.institutionid = '1419'
                    group by
                        ito2.orderid ) AS PreCount
                on ito.orderid = PreCount.orderid
            LEFT JOIN ordertosection ots 
                ON ito.orderid = ots.orderid
                JOIN journalsections js 
                    ON ots.sectionid = js.sectionid
            LEFT JOIN institutions i 
                ON ito.institutionid = i.institutionid
    WHERE
        ito.institutionid = '1419'
    GROUP BY
        -- via Transitive Property, since o.orderid = ito.orderid,
        -- use the primary table in the query's orderID for group/order by
        ito.orderid
    ORDER BY 
        ito.orderid DESC;
```

As per comments from O. Jones, I completely agree with inequality testing on your order's VOIDED and SUSPENDED filters.  What ARE the choices for those values... only 0 or 1 where a 1 indicates VOIDED or SUSPENDED? or do they have other values.  I have adjusted to equality = 0 (meaning NOT voided and NOT suspended)

Answer (score 0):

```
o:    (orderid, dateend)
ito:  (institutionid, orderid)
ots:  (orderid, sectionid)
js:   (sectionid, isbundle, is_science_education, title)
i:    (institutionid)
sd:   (orderid, dateend, datestart)
```

The order of the columns is generally important.  If any of those columns is too big (eg, if `title` is `TEXT`), then leave it off.  Otherwise, most of those are "covering" indexes, thereby giving a little extra performance boost.

The `ito` column order is important to handle DRapp's ito2